# Image texture passed through emission shows up in render window, not in camera view, shading window or final render

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, image

Good morning,

I'm trying to use an image texture on an emitting material. As pictured in this screenshot, the texture coordinates are generated. Although it shows up in the render window, it does neither in the camera view, nor in the shading window, nor in the final render.

[image: Camera view, Render window and shading view]

Thank you very much for your help, have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I found the answer to my own question. The issue was with camera range ! And it is because the shading mode had camera view activated in the preview window that it did not show there either.